# ANSI C: how can I include and then extract .exe file in my application (pack .exe into .exe)?

Tags: c, windows

I'm writing a program, which creates Windows service. So I need two .exe files - one for program, creating service and another for service itself. But I want to combine these two files into one. I have the following idea - open .exe file, which I want to pack (service application) in text editor and then copy its contents to some string. Then I need to create an empty .exe file in required directory and write the string to this file. But I suppose that's not a good idea. What is the best way to solve my problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a windows service installer?

Comment: Copying to a text editor is the worst possible idea. It won't preserve non-ASCII characters. Anyway, the executable is not raw machine code, concatenating two files won't work.

Comment: Well, first of all, ANSI C doesn't have a clue what an .exe file is. The Visual Studio compiler - and presumably others - lets you pack resources into your resulting executable, so you could just put an archive containing the exe you need and unpack that from the exe you run. Although I still don't quite understand what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: _>Although I still don't quite understand what exactly you're trying to do_

When you create Windows service you need to specify the path to the service executable file, right? So I want to extract preliminarily  this file from creating program (of course I can just put it manually in specified directory or just replace it to the directory by creating program, but I prefer to have just one file).

Comment: Well, I will try to this with Visual Studio, thanks.

Comment: You could combine them. A program can register (or uninstall) itself as a service.

Comment: I have posted an example of Seki's suggestion below -- it's in C++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For fun I wrote a "launcher" program that uses your method. It works, I tested it with zoomin.exe as the payload.

Once you've created the launcher executable, open both it and the payload file (zoomin.exe in my case) in [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/), and copy (using the Edit | Paste Special | Copy Binary Content and Paste Binary Content menu options).

You can find whereabouts in the launcher file the payload goes by searching in Notepad++ for "File Goes Here" and "End".

*Note, I do **not** recommend this in any way, it's fiddly, error-prone and can break easily with different compiler settings*.   The way I have solved this in the past is, as already commented, to add the payload as a resource, which is much more maintainable.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE_OF_ZOOMIN_EXE 11264
char buffer[SIZE_OF_ZOOMIN_EXE] = "File Goes Here";
char end_of_buffer[] = "End";

int main()
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("myzoomin.exe", "wb");
    fwrite(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, fp);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Here's an main() function for a self-installing service I wrote in C++ . In addition, the program  allows the service to be run interactively.

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) 
{ 
    SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY   DispatchTable[] = 
    { 
        { SERVICE_NAME,      Eng3ServiceStart      }, 
        { NULL,              NULL          } 
    }; 

    try {
        if (argc >= 2) {
            if (argc >= 3)
                if (!(logfile = fopen(argv[2], "a")))
                    logfile = stdout;

            if (0 == _stricmp(argv[1], "install")) {
                DeleteEng3Service(); // ignore return value -- don't care if error
                return CreateEng3Service();
            }
            else if (0 == _stricmp(argv[1], "uninstall"))
                return DeleteEng3Service() ;

        } 

        // not installing or uninstalling, start the service,
        // passing it all the command-line arguments.
        if (!StartServiceCtrlDispatcher( DispatchTable ) ) {
            if (GetLastError() == ERROR_FAILED_SERVICE_CONTROLLER_CONNECT) {
                fprintf(logfile, "Failed to connect to service. Starting in console mode.\n");
                return svcmain(argc, argv);
            }
            throw sys_ex();
        }

    } catch (exception& ex ) {
        fprintf(logfile, ex.what());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for such detailed answer. Even though I had already written my program using resources in Visual Studio (it's quite easy), I think your answer would be useful for somebody in the future :-)

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to add binary data as a [resouce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468900%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to a win32 executable.

Using the [win32 resource functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468902%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) this should be feasible.

Googling brought up this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4221/Adding-and-extracting-binary-resources